# How can I stop and resume my implemented ApplicationListener class?

Tags: android, rendering, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I have class WallpaperAndDream implements ApplicationListener. All realized by ligdx(live wallpaper and daydream).
Here is methods of creates and render:

```
public void create() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    camera.position.set(width / 2, height / 2, 0);
    bg.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
}


public void render() {
    GL10 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();

    gl.glClearColor(bg_red, bg_green, bg_blue, 1f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    camera.position.set(width / 2, height / 2, 0);
    camera.update();
    camera.apply(Gdx.gl10);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    BitmapFont font;
    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setScale(3.0f);
    font.setColor(Color.RED);

    font.draw(batch, BouncerDaydream.maxLight+" "+BouncerDaydream.thisLight, 100, 100);

    batch.end();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(update_interval);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
}
```

When i have daydream after live wallpaper it draw all alternately, but i need pause(or stop) daydream in this time and resume it when it is visible, how can i do this?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but for creating live wallpaper you should extends AndroidLiveWallpaperService, and for Daydreams extends AndroidDaydream.

There is more informations on this page : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-&-configuration